# How do I access files created by Ubuntu while using Windows (files created on NTFS disk)

Tags: windows-7, linux, windows, ubuntu, ntfs

I've created a folder called 'Video' in `E:\` using Ubuntu. When I switch to Windows I can't see it. How do I access the contents of this folder?

Note: the folder is also hidden in Ubuntu and not visible using the `ls` command.

I can see the folder using the EveryThing search engine, but after trying to open it I got a message like this:

I can see here:
[image]

I can't open:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you really created the file where you claim. If you can't see the file listed when you invoke `ls -la` in its directory, then the file is not actually there.

Comment: I've create a Folder in Ubuntu and copy some files into it ... now I can't see this folder and content in Ubuntu and windows only way to sure it actually there is the everything search engine that find some files when I'm search but while opening it via this application I got an error that told me no file it may you write path wrong

Comment: To make sure you create the file where you claim please use the command `mkdir` on the shell. You probably have a problem in the paths Linux and Windows are seeing. It might be a mount point conflict.

Comment: to make the issue more clear I've create a folder called `Video` and copy some files into this folder, after copying files I run some videos from this folder normally without any problems, but after restart my computer I've unable to see the folder and files, either on Ubuntu or Windows :)

Answer (score 0):

#### When I switch to Windows I can't see it

You can't see it because the folder is hidden.

You can configure Explorer to show hidden files, folders and drives as follows:

> 1. Open "Folder Options" by
>
>    - clicking on "Start" [image],
>    - clicking "Control Panel",
>    - clicking "Appearance and Personalization", and then
>    - clicking "Folder Options".
> 2. Click the "View" tab.
> 3. Under "Advanced settings",
>
>    - click "Show hidden files, folders, and drives", and then
>    - click "OK".

Source [Show hidden files](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/show-hidden-files#show-hidden-files=windows-7)

Comment: No it's not hidden and I can see it when I'm search for any files in 'Video' Folder using everyThing search engine ...... I've tried it before .

Comment: Your question says "Viedo". Perhaps you are looking for the wrong folder?

Comment: written mistake :) I mean Viedo not Video

Comment: really I mean Video but it is written mistake I'm just confused ... don't focus on file name the case is important for me I'm sure I'm chose the write folder